# How do I fix the package problem I have received after a failed attempt at installing QtOctave?

Tags: 12.10, package-management, octave

I installed GNU Octave 3.6.4 today straight after it was released via the commands:

```
cd ~/octave-3.6.4
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /home/brentonhorne/octave-3.6.4/run-octave /usr/bin/octave
```

which succeeded in installing it (even though without the last line it didn't in the sense that running `octave` from the command-line didn't call it).

I did this after I had removed the previous version that's currently the only version available in the software centre on Quantal (i.e. GNU Octave 3.6.3).

I then tried to install qtoctave because it was removed with GNU Octave 3.6.3 when I ran `sudo apt-get remove octave`. Upon running `sudo apt-get install -f` I received the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up octave (3.6.3-2~ppa1~quantal2) ...
error: couldn't read directory /usr/local/share/octave/packages: No such file or directory
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/share/octave/3.6.4/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 541, column 7
error:   /usr/local/share/octave/3.6.4/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 472, column 25

dpkg: error processing octave (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 octave
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Be careful, this can damage your installation!**

Find the package which is not properly installed and copy or remember the name of the package:

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep octave
```

Try to remove it (maybe some errors):

```
sudo dpkg --remove <package>
```

Try to purge

```
sudo dpkg --purge <package>
```

Try to do `sudo apt-get -f install` again.

Comment: So do I remove each individual package listed by sudo dpkg --list | grep octave?