# "subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2" errors while trying to remove postgresql-client-common

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and trying to remove postgresql-client-common from my machine, but I'm getting these errors:

```
E: postgresql-9.2: subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
E: postgresql-client-9.2: subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
E: postgresql-common: subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
```

I've tried: `sudo apt-get -f install`, but it fails also:

```
lucid@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  postgresql-9.2 postgresql-client-9.2 postgresql-client-common
  postgresql-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 561 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 23.6MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 131347 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing postgresql-9.2 ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed pre-removal script: Exec format error
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.2 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-installation script: Exec format error
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Removing postgresql-client-9.2 ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed pre-removal script: Exec format error
dpkg: error processing postgresql-client-9.2 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Removing postgresql-common ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed pre-removal script: Exec format error
dpkg: error processing postgresql-common (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Removing postgresql-client-common ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-removal script: Exec format error
dpkg: error processing postgresql-client-common (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.2
 postgresql-client-9.2
 postgresql-common
 postgresql-client-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to I fix this?

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I described an solution for a similar problem. Maybe it fixes your problem too.

[How do I fix the package problem I have received after a failed attempt at installing QtOctave?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259750/how-do-i-fix-the-package-problem-i-have-received-after-a-failed-attempt-at-insta/259798#259798)