# Having trouble installing octave packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, octave

I am having trouble installing anything octave related. This includes through the apt-get command, and the pkg install within octave interpreter. I looked around and it seems be something with my previous apt-get activity.

Bellow is the display I always get when installing anything to octave. I've attempted to install the dependencies specified to be missing. But when I do it tells me they are already installed.

I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS, octave 3.8.1

any assistance is appreciated.

```
 daniel:apt$ sudo apt-get install octave-pkg-dev
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
  libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
  libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
 daniel:apt$
```

Comment: Can you try the following line: `sudo apt-get install octave-pkg-dev libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 gstreamer1.0-clutter libcogl-pango15`

Comment: This fixed it along with other commands. Posting it here as an edit here so it may help the next person.

Comment: The unmet dependencies are probably not related to the octave package. They might be left overs from a previous package installation.

Comment: -_-... This didn't work correctly. After rebooting my drivers started to cry... Had to reinstall ubuntu to fix them. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
sudo apt-get remove octave
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install octave-pkg-dev libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 gstreamer1.0-clutter libcogl-pango15
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259750/how-do-i-fix-the-package-problem-i-have-received-after-a-failed-attempt-at-insta) is where I found the additional commands.

EDIT: not a good solution. Installing octave with the other dependencies caused my drivers to through a temper tantrum. Had to reinstall ubuntu for everything to get back to normal.

**EDIT 2 - ABSOLUTE FIX:** for the love of all that is holy. I am flipping my swear finger ubuntu and octave. If I want to install any octave packages I must install it using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install octave-<package_name_you_want>
```

then to make sure the package is installed, just type within the octave interpreter

```
ver
```

and I promise you, the package will be there. Solution was found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/i-cant-install-matlab-on-ubuntu-4175499684/)